# SQLAlchemy with_variant() for MySQL and MariaDB

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm trying to run this example,

[image]

but I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Variant.with_variant() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

My code:

```py
class RuiMartinsTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'RuiMartins'

    hits = Column(
        Integer().with_variant(
            postgresql.INTEGER, "postgresql"
        ).with_variant(
            mysql.INTEGER(unsigned=True), "mysql", "mariadb"
        ),
        unique=False,
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
        comment="bla bla bla"
    )
```

But if I remove `, "mariadb"`, it works:

My code:

```py
class RuiMartinsTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'RuiMartins'

    hits = Column(
        Integer().with_variant(
            postgresql.INTEGER, "postgresql"
        ).with_variant(
            mysql.INTEGER(unsigned=True), "mysql"
        ),
        unique=False,
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
        comment="bla bla bla"
    )
```

Any recommendation?
Thanks

---

**UPDATE:** Fixed here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/8408

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened is you tried to specify two `dialect_name` parameters in a [`with_variant`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_api.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeEngine.with_variant) which only accepts one (in SQLAlchemy < 2.0):

> *method* `sqlalchemy.types.TypeEngine.with_variant(type_, dialect_name)`

You need to use one `with_variant` for each dialect you want to specify.

**NB.** In SQLAlchemy 2.0, [`with_variant`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_api.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeEngine.with_variant) accepts one or more `dialect_names`.

> *method* `sqlalchemy.types.TypeEngine.with_variant(type_: _TypeEngineArgument[Any], *dialect_names: str) → SelfTypeEngine`

Looks like the example https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#using-uppercase-and-backend-specific-types-for-multiple-backends is wrong for `1.x`.

PS. created [github issue#8408](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/8408) to track this documentation issue.